# Best practice on index usage with timestamp

Tags: index

I have a query to find period tasks, it runs calculation and scans the whole table.

```
UPDATE task SET status = ?
WHERE cron_hour != 0
AND (status = ? OR status = ?)
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - end_time > cron_hour * 3600
```

I think the last condition will not use the index on end_time, what's the best practice here?

Answer (score 0):

create an index on `( cron_hour * 3600 + end_time )`

then write check in the where clause as

```
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) > cron_hour * 3600 + end_time
```

but you might find an index on status to be more useful